# Doctrine2 repositories, multiple dirs

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm refactoring and placing my doctrine2 entites/repositories and maybe proxies into separate folders.

I have it set up to read multiple entity directories, but i'm integrating with zend framework and my models have a `_` namespace , `Admin_Model_Repository_User` instead of `Application\Entity\Repository\User`  .

Anyone have any pointers for managing multiple paths for proxies and repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about proxies, but you can certainly specify multiple entity and repositories locations easily.

When creating the driver, you can pass either a single path string or an array. For example for xml:

```
$driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(array(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/models',
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/models'
));
```

Or with annotations:

```
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/models',
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/models'
));
```

This works on any mapping driver. Or you can call addPath() on the $driverImpl after it is created.

For repositories if you specify the repository class in the mapping, as long as an autoloader can access it then it will work in any location.

Comment: hey thanks, yeah I got it reading the entities from multiple paths, possibly repositories, but I'm not sure how doctrine loads the proxies. Just for good measure I let doctrine create the proxy but whenever I go to use that entity I get this:      `The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Admin_Model_Admin" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called`

Comment: Make sure you have an autoloader that can load up Admin_Model_Admin. Although I thought Doctrine did that itself when it loaded the mapping files. It basically means that an object of a class is being unserialized before the class itself is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks, you got me on the right track. I was using zend_auth to persist the entity through session storage, and I was calling `getIdentity()->getId()` , which it didn't like. Works fine without separating the entity dirs, but its no problem atm, I just persisted the id into storage and had my class recreate the object from the id.

It seems to be working now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

My Solution for ZF2

in file module.doctrine_orm.local.config.php

```
'drivers' => array(
        'Admin' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'namespace' => 'Admin\Model',
            'paths' => array('module/Admin/src/Admin/Model')
        ),
        'Accounting' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'namespace' => 'Accounting\Model',
            'paths' => array('module/Accounting/src/Accounting/Model')
        )
    ),
```

and

```
'orm_driver_chain' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'drivers' => array(
                        'application_annotation_driver' => $settings['drivers']['Accounting'],
                        'application_annotation_driver2' => $settings['drivers']['Admin']
                    ),
                    'cache' => $settings['cache']
                )
            ),
```